# Error when trying to claim interface for WebUSB

Tags: javascript, web, webusb

I am trying to use WebUSB in order to read data from a physical ID scanner on a website. However, when I try to claim the interface I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'claimInterface' on 'USBDevice': The requested interface implements a protected class.
```

This error happens with every USB device I plug in. I tried an Arduino, a Blue Snowball microphone, a gamepad, almost everything. No luck.

I feel it's important to know that I did come across sources saying this error is due to the device not supporting WebUSB, but I feel that is highly unlikely as I tried a wide variety of USB devices.

My current JS code:

```js
let usbReader;
        document.querySelector("#header").addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
            navigator.usb.requestDevice({filters:[/*{vendorId: 3468}*/]}).then(function(device){
                console.log(device);
                (navigator.usb.getDevices().then((p)=>{
                    if(p.length > 0){
                        usbReader = p[0];
                        usbConnected();
                    }
                }));
             });
        });

        function usbConnected(){
            usbReader.open()
                .then(()=>usbReader.selectConfiguration(1))
                .then(()=>usbReader.claimInterface(2)); // line in which the error occurs
        }
```

It's also important to know I tried switching the configuration and interfaces.

Comment: Did you try interfaces other than 2?

Comment: Yep, as stated before, I tried other configurations and interfaces.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebUSB: The requested interface implements a protected class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54910706/webusb-the-requested-interface-implements-a-protected-class)

Comment: I solved the issue using HID instead. I'm not sure if the link you sent presents the issue in my case as I had the same error for all USB devices I tested it on.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using WebHID instead. Input now works great!

```js
let device;

document.querySelector("#header").addEventListener("click", async (e) => {
  device = (await navigator.hid.requestDevice({filters:[]}))[0];
  console.log(device);
  device.open();
  device.oninputreport = function(inp) {
    console.log(inp.data.getUint8(0));
  }
});
```